Scala Akka HTTP Postgresql how to efficiently insert a case class's data into different tables
I’m building a Scala application using Akka HTTP, SBT, PgSQL and doobie.
The app’s API receives JSON data formatted as a Table case class.
The data should then be inserted into a PostgreSql database.
The database has width, height, area, and tables as different tables.
The aim is to store each of the corresponding case class fields into their own tables in the PgSQL table.
Is the code below the best way to do it, or is there a more efficient way of achieving it?
Is there a way of optimizing the 4  different queries into one query?
case class Width(id: String, width: Int)
case class Height(id: String, height: Long)
case class Area(id: String, area: Long)
case class Table(id: String, width:Long, height: Height, area:Area)

def dbCreate(xa: pgConfig, table: Table): Unit = {

val widthId = sql”INSERT INTO widths (id, width) VALUES ($table.id}, ${table.width})”
.update
.withUniqueGeneratedKeys[Int](“id”)
.transact(xa)
.unsafeRunSync

val heightId = sql”INSERT INTO heights (id, height) VALUES (${table.id}, ${table.height.height})”
.update
.withUniqueGeneratedKeys[Int](“id”)
.transact(xa)
.unsafeRunSync

val areaId = sql”INSERT INTO areas (id, area) VALUES (${table.id}, ${table.area.area})”
.update
.withUniqueGeneratedKeys[Int](“id”)
.transact(xa)
.unsafeRunSync

sql”INSERT INTO tables (id, width_id, height_id, area_id) VALUES (${table.id}, $widthId, $heightId, $areaId)”
.update
.transact(xa)
.unsafeRunSync
}


I'm having some serious doubts about this datamodel, but don't have the details from the data to confirm my doubts. Another issue is the XA transaction, do you really need that? It has a big (negative) performance impact on your application.

I don't understand all the context. Are you using flyway to persist data each time you receive an http request in some endpoint of your REST API service? The sql string interpolator doesn't look like it's something from flyway, could be from slick? Another lib? Flyway let you handle schema evolution through sql scripts or Java/scala code, but it's something you run outside your service

in the case class the id field is String but in the database it is Int. Their types should match. It seems to me that you are using doobie. You should be able to write a function that returns all 4 objects and executes the unsafeRunSync only once.

Yes am using Doobie. Was simply asking if it's possible to combine all queries into one. That would be monotonous if dealing with a large number of case classes.

You can combine several queries into a single transaction (ConnectionIO). If you want to send each piece of data (e.g. id) to DB once, and then make it use it several times in several places, it's possible - as long as you write an SQL which would take each of the values only once, e.g. by putting it into temp table, or using some stored procedure. Doobie simply uses parametrized queries with ? (lowest common denomiator), which allows using each param exactly once and they need to be passed in order they are used (and that's handled by Doobie).
